# GitHub Actions rsync command not found

Tags: github, github-actions

Just like what the title says, how do I fix this? I don't think there's anything wrong with the rsync command. So I'm not really sure why it's giving me this error.

[Click here for the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWH2B.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Looks like rsync isn't present in the runner machine. You need to install it first.

Comment: I was curious and I just created a [setup rsync action](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/setup-rsync) supported on all OS. I guess your problem there is that you weren't using an ubuntu runner (where the rsync command is configured by default).

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry I didn't know that. And thanks for the answers/hints as well. I'll try them.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, rsync was not installed in the virtual machine. I installed it and it works now. Thank you.